Is the DKIM example in RFC 6376 (and RFC 4871) valid?
I've been fighting with this over the years, and just can't let go of it. No matter what I try I can't understand the DKIM email signing example in Appendix A. I've followed the errata which corrected the headers in the example, whose very existence suggests it should work.  The body hash works out as expected, but the signature I calculate does not.  I'm wondering if the example is defective, or what I'm misunderstanding about how it's supposed to work.
Private key from Appendix C in RFC 6376
const string RSA_PRIVATE_KEY = @"   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   MIICXwIBAAKBgQDwIRP/UC3SBsEmGqZ9ZJW3/DkMoGeLnQg1fWn7/zYtIxN2SnFC
   jxOCKG9v3b4jYfcTNh5ijSsq631uBItLa7od+v/RtdC2UzJ1lWT947qR+Rcac2gb
   to/NMqJ0fzfVjH4OuKhitdY9tf6mcwGjaNBcWToIMmPSPDdQPNUYckcQ2QIDAQAB
   AoGBALmn+XwWk7akvkUlqb+dOxyLB9i5VBVfje89Teolwc9YJT36BGN/l4e0l6QX
   /1//6DWUTB3KI6wFcm7TWJcxbS0tcKZX7FsJvUz1SbQnkS54DJck1EZO/BLa5ckJ
   gAYIaqlA9C0ZwM6i58lLlPadX/rtHb7pWzeNcZHjKrjM461ZAkEA+itss2nRlmyO
   n1/5yDyCluST4dQfO8kAB3toSEVc7DeFeDhnC1mZdjASZNvdHS4gbLIA1hUGEF9m
   3hKsGUMMPwJBAPW5v/U+AWTADFCS22t72NUurgzeAbzb1HWMqO4y4+9Hpjk5wvL/
   eVYizyuce3/fGke7aRYw/ADKygMJdW8H/OcCQQDz5OQb4j2QDpPZc0Nc4QlbvMsj
   7p7otWRO5xRa6SzXqqV3+F0VpqvDmshEBkoCydaYwc2o6WQ5EBmExeV8124XAkEA
   qZzGsIxVP+sEVRWZmW6KNFSdVUpk3qzK0Tz/WjQMe5z0UunY9Ax9/4PVhp/j61bf
   eAYXunajbBSOLlx4D+TunwJBANkPI5S9iylsbLs6NkaMHV6k5ioHBBmgCak95JGX
   GMot/L2x0IYyMLAz6oLWh2hm7zwtb0CgOrPo1ke44hFYnfc=
   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

Headers from sample message and signature in Appendix A, with the signature header including body hash appended to the signed headers, as described in section 3.7
const string HEADERS = @"Received: from client1.football.example.com  [192.0.2.1]
      by submitserver.example.com with SUBMISSION;
      Fri, 11 Jul 2003 21:01:54 -0700 (PDT)
From: Joe SixPack <joe@football.example.com>
To: Suzie Q <suzie@shopping.example.net>
Subject: Is dinner ready?
Date: Fri, 11 Jul 2003 21:00:37 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <20030712040037.46341.5F8J@football.example.com>
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; s=brisbane; d=example.com;
      c=simple/simple; q=dns/txt; i=joe@football.example.com;
      h=Received : From : To : Subject : Date : Message-ID;
      bh=2jUSOH9NhtVGCQWNr9BrIAPreKQjO6Sn7XIkfJVOzv8=;
      b=";

const string EXPECTED_SIGNATURE = "AuUoFEfDxTDkHlLXSZEpZj79LICEps6eda7W3deTVFOk4yAUoqOB4nujc7YopdG5dWLSdNg6xNAZpOPr+kHxt1IrE+NahM6L/LbvaHutKVdkLLkpVaVVQPzeRDI009SO2Il5Lu7rDNH6mZckBdrIx0orEtZV4bmp/YzhwvcubU4=";

And finally the logic in question.  This has gotten much more concise over time as the various cryptographic functions have been added to the framework, but I've always arrived at the same unexpected signature.
var rsa = System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Create();

rsa.ImportFromPem(RSA_PRIVATE_KEY);

var signature = rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HEADERS),
    System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
    System.Security.Cryptography.RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

var signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);

Assert.Equal(EXPECTED_SIGNATURE, signatureString);

And for what it's worth, this is what I've calculated
PgpOeOGQgKDzYvwezymrJpa2KzjMkcOF86HaZNagCNuOwPMW67T+PgNfb1LyGeey07FsOhBQuQVUm36BFyvu8V3w6B/LYJITIfiC+GUA/C8/iJUTswSv9NOeZnjsebstqjI4LTuXRDqmQqex9TbW/8SA2rlZwegAyg0biKj75pg=

UPDATE:
After a suggestion from @jstedfast I tried the same logic with the example from RFC8463, which uses different canonicalization and a different private key.  Using those, I get the expected signature from that example.  So the original question still stands.

F45dVWDfMbQDGHJFlXUNB2HKfbCeLRyhDXgFpEL8GwpsRe0IeIixNTe3DhCVlUrSjV4BwcVcOF6+FF3Zo9Rpo1tFOeS9mPYQTnGdaSGsgeefOsk2JzdA+L10TeYt9BgDfQNZtKdN1WO//KgIqXP7OdEFE4LjFYNcUxZQ4FADY+8=

const string RFC8463_PRIVATE_KEY = @"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   MIICXQIBAAKBgQDkHlOQoBTzWRiGs5V6NpP3idY6Wk08a5qhdR6wy5bdOKb2jLQi
   Y/J16JYi0Qvx/byYzCNb3W91y3FutACDfzwQ/BC/e/8uBsCR+yz1Lxj+PL6lHvqM
   KrM3rG4hstT5QjvHO9PzoxZyVYLzBfO2EeC3Ip3G+2kryOTIKT+l/K4w3QIDAQAB
   AoGAH0cxOhFZDgzXWhDhnAJDw5s4roOXN4OhjiXa8W7Y3rhX3FJqmJSPuC8N9vQm
   6SVbaLAE4SG5mLMueHlh4KXffEpuLEiNp9Ss3O4YfLiQpbRqE7Tm5SxKjvvQoZZe
   zHorimOaChRL2it47iuWxzxSiRMv4c+j70GiWdxXnxe4UoECQQDzJB/0U58W7RZy
   6enGVj2kWF732CoWFZWzi1FicudrBFoy63QwcowpoCazKtvZGMNlPWnC7x/6o8Gc
   uSe0ga2xAkEA8C7PipPm1/1fTRQvj1o/dDmZp243044ZNyxjg+/OPN0oWCbXIGxy
   WvmZbXriOWoSALJTjExEgraHEgnXssuk7QJBALl5ICsYMu6hMxO73gnfNayNgPxd
   WFV6Z7ULnKyV7HSVYF0hgYOHjeYe9gaMtiJYoo0zGN+L3AAtNP9huqkWlzECQE1a
   licIeVlo1e+qJ6Mgqr0Q7Aa7falZ448ccbSFYEPD6oFxiOl9Y9se9iYHZKKfIcst
   o7DUw1/hz2Ck4N5JrgUCQQCyKveNvjzkkd8HjYs0SwM0fPjK16//5qDZ2UiDGnOe
   uEzxBDAr518Z8VFbR41in3W4Y3yCDgQlLlcETrS+zYcL
   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

const string RFC8463_HEADERS = @"from:Joe SixPack <joe@football.example.com>
to:Suzie Q <suzie@shopping.example.net>
subject:Is dinner ready?
date:Fri, 11 Jul 2003 21:00:37 -0700 (PDT)
message-id:<20030712040037.46341.5F8J@football.example.com>
dkim-signature:v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=football.example.com; i=@football.example.com; q=dns/txt; s=test; t=1528637909; h=from : to : subject : date : message-id : from : subject : date; bh=2jUSOH9NhtVGCQWNr9BrIAPreKQjO6Sn7XIkfJVOzv8=; b=";



I figured out the body hash. I'm going to try for the remainder. The body of the message is the base64 decoding of SGkuDQoNCldlIGxvc3QgdGhlIGdhbWUuIEFyZSB5b3UgaHVuZ3J5IHlldD8NCg0KSm9lLg0K

Have you read section 3.7? It doesn't look like your code comes even close to matching what that section requires.

Can you be more specific than not even coming close?  Per 3.7,  step one is to hash the body.  As stated, I get the expected result there.  Then in step 2, we are to pass the headers identified in the 'h' tag, in the same order they appear in the 'h' tag, followed by the dkim header, which includes the body hash.  That's exactly what I believe I'm doing.

Maybe it is that simple. The RFC is so poorly written it's hard to be certain how to process the header fields.

Well, thanks for looking at it.  This is a minimum code example, but I believe it's correct. The full implementation produces signatures which are found to be valid using tools such as https://dkimvalidator.com.  I first stumbled on this when I was implementing and writing tests for RFC 4871 before it was obsoleted , and it uses the same example.  The student in me says I must be missing something, but the cynic in me says the RFC authors missed something.

I implemented this for MimeKit and the example works fine (it's the same example as the one in rfc8463).
I haven't bothered to look into the code to remind myself of the implementation, but my recollection from years ago is that you need to include the trailing CRLF sequence at the end of the DKIM-Signature header:
const string HEADERS = @"Received: from client1.football.example.com  [192.0.2.1]
      by submitserver.example.com with SUBMISSION;
      Fri, 11 Jul 2003 21:01:54 -0700 (PDT)
From: Joe SixPack <joe@football.example.com>
To: Suzie Q <suzie@shopping.example.net>
Subject: Is dinner ready?
Date: Fri, 11 Jul 2003 21:00:37 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <20030712040037.46341.5F8J@football.example.com>
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; s=brisbane; d=example.com;
      c=simple/simple; q=dns/txt; i=joe@football.example.com;
      h=Received : From : To : Subject : Date : Message-ID;
      bh=2jUSOH9NhtVGCQWNr9BrIAPreKQjO6Sn7XIkfJVOzv8=;
      b=
";

See if that gets the correct results. If not, make sure that the line endings in your literal string are actually CRLF and not just LF (which might very well be the case if you are testing this on Linux/Mac).

Definitely CRLF's, and I've tried with and without a trailing CRLF.  The example looks like the one in RFC8463, except that in that one it's relaxed/relaxed whereas here it's simple/simple, which obviously means the signature is going to be different.

I went a step further, and using the rsa-sha256 example from RFC8463 (different private key and canonicalization), and I do get the expected result.

Ah, yea you are right about the relaxed/relaxed bit, I missed that.
